# CMD to delete a specific folder with files from multiple folder paths

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line-interface, batch-processing, command-prompt

I need a CMD batch file to delete all the log files. 
My company makes plugins for their product and the path is something as follows:

```
C:/Program Files/product/../plugins/../plugin_Path/pluginOne/audit/log
C:/Program Files/product/../plugins/../plugin_Path/pluginOne/audit/log-archive
C:/Program Files/product/../Root/plugins/../plugin_Path/pluginTwo/audit/log
C:/Program Files/product/../Root/plugins/../plugin_Path/pluginTwo/audit/log-archive
```

Now I need to delete all the log and log-archive folders with its contains.

Currently I wrote a samll program like this:

```
@echo off
color 02
for %%A in (
    "C:/Program Files/product/plugins/plugin_Path/pluginOne/audit/log"
    "C:/Program Files/product/plugins/plugin_Path/pluginOne/audit/log-archive"
    "C:/Program Files/product/plugins/plugin_Path/pluginTwo/audit/log"
    "C:/Program Files/product/plugins/plugin_Path/pluginTwo/audit/log-archive"
    ) do (
    del /Q %%A
    echo Deleted %%A
)

echo All files deleted
pause
echo Program ended
```

But here I need to insert all the log paths ***manually***. 
I am looking for a solution where I could point the parent folder (say Program Files/Company) and it could traverse all the files inside and will delete all the log and log-archival folders with its contains. 
I am a QA person have good QA experience but no experience on batch programming and I dont have much time and support team is not present. *[Need help]*. There are ***more than 1K log files are present***.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `RD` command from the parent directory, maybe with the `/S` option? _Enter `RD /?` at the Command Prompt for the command usage information._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as explained by the Microsoft documentation [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file), the directory separator on Windows is `\` and not `/` as on Linux/Mac. `/` is used on Windows for options as you can see on your code for example on `/Q`. So use in future `\` in file/folder paths. The Windows file system accessing kernel functions automatically replace all forward slashes by backslashes before accessing the file systems, but writing code depending on automatic error correction is never a good idea.

The task to delete all folders with name `log` or `log-archive` in a specified folder and all its subfolders can be done with a single command line.

```
@for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%ProgramFiles%\product\plugins\plugin_Path\log*" /AD /B /S 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /R "\\log \\log-archive"') do @rd /Q /S "%%I" 2>nul
```

**FOR** with option `/F` runs in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` (more precise with `%ComSpec% /C`) in background the command line in `'`... `'` which is here:

```
dir "C:\Program Files\product\plugins\plugin_Path\log*" /AD /B /S 2>nul | C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /R "\\log \\log-archive"
```

The command **DIR** outputs to handle **STDOUT**

- in bare format because of option `/B`
- just directories because of option `/AD` (attribute directory)
- directory names matching the wildcard pattern `log*`
- in specified directory `C:\Program Files\product\plugins\plugin_Path`
- and all its subdirectories because of option `/S`
- with full path also because of option `/S`.

It could be that **DIR** does not find any file system entry matching these criteria. In this case an error message is output by **DIR** to handle **STDERR**. This error output is redirected with `2>nul` to device **NUL** to suppress it.

The standard output of **DIR** is redirected with `|` to handle **STDIN** of **FINDSTR** which runs

- because of option `/I` a case-insensitive
- regular expression find explicitly requested with option `/R`
- for string `\log` **or** `\log-archive` (space is interpreted as OR)
- which must be found at end of a line because of option `/E`.

All lines matching these search criteria are output by **FINDSTR** to handle **STDOUT** of background command process. This filtering of output of **DIR** with **FINDSTR** is necessary to avoid the deletion of a directory which is named for example `LogToKeep` also found and output by **DIR**.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** with option `/F` captures output to handle **STDOUT** of started command process and processes this output line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself. Empty lines are always ignored by **FOR** which do not occur here. Lines starting with a semicolon are also ignored by default because of `eol=;` is the default definition for end of line option. But a full qualified folder path cannot contain a semicolon at beginning because the folder path starts either with a drive letter or with a backslash in case of a UNC path. So default end of line option can be kept in this case. **FOR** would split up by default every line into substrings with using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and would assign just first space/tab separated string to specified loop variable. This line splitting behavior is not wanted here as the folder path contains definitely a space character and the entire folder path is needed and not just the string up to first space. For that reason `delims=` is used to specify an empty list of delimiters which disables line splitting behavior.

**FOR** executes for every directory output by **DIR** passing **FINDSTR** filter with full path the command **RD** to remove the directory quietly because of option `/Q` and with all files and subdirectories because of `/S`.

The deletion of the directory could fail because of missing NTFS permissions, or the directory to delete or one of its subdirectories is current directory of a running process, or a file in the directory to delete is currently opened by a running process in a manner which denies deletion of the file while being opened, or the directory to delete does not exist anymore because it was deleted already before in **FOR** loop. The error message output by command **RD** to handle **STDERR** is in this case redirected to device **NUL** to suppress it.

Please note that command **RD** deletes all `log` and `log-archives` directories and not just the files and subdirectories in these directories. It is unclear from your question what exactly should be deleted by the batch file.

It is of course also possible to replace `rd /Q /S "%%I"` by `del /A /F /Q "%%I\*"` to delete just all files including hidden and read-only files quietly in the directory assigned with full path to loop variable `I`.

`@` left to command **FOR** and command **RD** just suppress the output of those commands before execution by Windows command processor `cmd.exe`. Both `@` are not needed if this single command line is used in a batch file containing before `@echo off`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `rd /?`

Comment: Since this goes into such depth, I think it's important to mention that `%%I` refers to the result that will be iterated through in the for-loop. "for `%%I` in result set, perform actions on each `%%I`." The `I` could be any desired name for the parameter/variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to remove the contents of the log and log-archive directories. This means the easiest solution would probably be [FORFILES](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html).

This will delete all the files under log and log-archive directories found within any subfolder of "C:\Program Files\product\plugins". The folders MUST be named exactly `log` or `log-archive`. It will not remove directories.

```
 FORFILES /P "C:\Program Files\product\plugins" /M log /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE DEL /s /q @path\*"
 FORFILES /P "C:\Program Files\product\plugins" /M log-archive /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE DEL /s /q @path\*"
```

You could also add a `/D` switch to only delete applicable files if they are older than a specific number of days. This will delete all the log and log-archive files under "C:\Program Files\product\plugins" that are older than 90 days:

```
 FORFILES /D -90 /P "C:\Program Files\product\plugins" /M log /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE DEL /s /q @path\*"
 FORFILES /D -90 /P "C:\Program Files\product\plugins" /M log-archive /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE DEL /s /q @path\*"
```

Comment: No. log and log-archive are directories. Consider this C:\Program Files\product\plugins\plugin_Path\pluginOne\audit\log\\*. Thank you in Advance

Comment: Yeah, with intermediate subdirectories —existing between 'plugins' & 'log'/'logarchive'— forfiles returns *ERROR: Files of type "log" not found*